# Show all commits in repository using git rebase

Tags: git, logging, rebase

I am running `git rebase HEAD~X` and I can't see all of the commits on the text editor which opens after I run this command, I have 6 commits that appears when I run `git log --all`.

Running `git rebase -i HEAD~2` shows only 2 to edit, **I'm not able to run anything beyond HEAD~3**, When I try, I get the error message:

> fatal: invalid upstream 'HEAD~6'

I believe this is happening because I previously ran 'git reset'. How can I view all six commits in `'git rebase'`?

### Edit

I have one repository which contains only one branch called "main" and 6 commits since the beginning: https://github.com/DevEsteves/WebScrapingWithPython

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to see all of the 6 commits on git rebase

All you can see in an interactive rebase todo list is the parent chain starting at where you are now (HEAD). If some of those 6 commits are not your direct parent / ancestor, you will not see them in the list.

> I have 6 commits that appears when I run `git log --all`

But that doesn't mean there are 6 ancestor commits between you and the start. Try

```
git log --all --oneline --decorate --graph
```

for a better look at where you are.

That said, note that you can likely get one more commit into your interactive rebase todo list by saying

```
git rebase -i --root
```